# Using an .axml file in my Xamarin.forms project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Its quite simple. I added a new .axml layout file in resources/layout folder of the Droid project in my XF project in VS2015, i don't just know how to link it from my shared project.

I want to load the .axml file from App.xaml.cs using the `#if __ANDROID__` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't

Long answer: Xamarin Forms has no idea about axml nor android views, it only knows about Forms views, so you can't create a native android view from a Forms page.

There are two solutions possible, one if you're creating a new full Activity and other if that's going to be a control.

If this is for a new Activity then a dependency service can do the task, you call the dependency service which will execute the native code to create the Activity using the axml.

The way to do this if it's just a control is to create a custom control on Forms and a custom renderer, then in the renderer you can load the axml on the native android view.

Anyway, I would avoid both, what you're trying to do that you can't do it on XAML?

Reference:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/